# How to make copy of IWebProxy?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

If I do:

```
var proxy1 = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
proxy1.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "pass123");

var proxy2 = WebRequest.GetSystemWebProxy();
proxy2.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin2", "pass123");
```

The credentials of proxy2 overwrite the credentials of proxy1. This is presumably because they are both referencing the same "system web proxy" under the hood. Is there a way to make a copy of the "system web proxy" such that I can guarantee proxy settings immutability after creating an `HttpClient`? Or is there some other way I can guarantee proxy settings immutability?

I know I could create a custom `WebProxy` object, but then I don't have the proxy address automatically populated like I do if I use `GetSystemWebProxy` and I don't know how to get the system proxy settings any other way.

Comment: Don’t use WebRequest. Use HttpClient directly

Comment: I am using HttpClient directly, with: `new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { Proxy = proxy1 });`. The problem is that the proxy settings are not immutable and can be corrupted if somewhere else in the code modifies the result of `GetSystemWebProxy`